# Installing cython>=0.24 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

How do I install cython>=0.24 on Ubuntu 14.04?

I need it for a pip package that requires this recent version of cython, but can't get it to install on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

The cython 2.4 package from the Ubuntu 17.04 repositories can be manually downloaded and installed in Ubuntu 14.04 without needing to install any other dependency packages.

1. Visit the official Ubuntu [package cython in zesty](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/cython) webpage.
2. Under the **Download cython** heading click the red link that matches your operating system's architecture (amd64 for 64-bit or i386 for 32-bit).
3. Download Page for cython_0.25.2-1_xxxx.deb will open up where instead of the string xxxx is substituted the architecture that you selected in step 2. Select a mirror that is near your physical location and download the cython .deb file.
4. Double-click the cython .deb file that you downloaded to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.
5. Run the following command to prevent cython from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold cython
   ```